# axios bypass TLS certificates error. No solution at all for FRONT END (React)

Tags: reactjs, ssl, axios, certificate

**[EDIT] : one answer below**

trying to call my node https backend from react using axios (of fetch)...
Always facing certificate errors for self signed ones. Can "by pass" the REJECT_UNAUTORIZED error by setting `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` when starting the react app, but this is clearly not the solution. I'm also facing different messages such as ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID.

Worth to mention that everything is running fine when using postman, when activating the certificate verification and uploading my self signed CA PEM certificate in postman.
I tried to do the same in chrome (uploading the self signed CA PEM certificate in the root CA Store) but without luck. Still the warning...

Of course I tried the solution to add an https agent (see code below), but this is also not fixing the issue.
That solution seems to be fine for NODE apps, but not from Front End apps in React or any other language,..

So what is the solution ? How we can request a local self signed https backend server from react without these warnings ?
There are millions of issues like this reported here or in axios github, but still no viable solution ?

Thks

```
axios.defaults.httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    port: 443,
  });


const tokensData = await axios.post<TLoginApi, AxiosResponse<TLoginApi, any>, TLoginDTO>(
    `${process.env.AUTH_URL}/login`,
    credentials,
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
      // or this but failed anyway httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
                                                  rejectUnauthorized: false,
                                                  port: 443,
                                                }),
    }
  );
```

Comment: Fix the common name in the subject and issuer field. You can regenerate a certificate if you have the key. You need to format it according to the ANSI X.500 rules for a distinguished name. See e.g. [this article](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.tcp.ipsec.ipsec.help.doc/com/ibm/tcp/ipsec/nss/NssImageServerPs.RB_X500.htm). ChatGPT also seems to know this pretty well :)

Answer (score 1):

answering my own question.
To avoid using `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`, you need to create your self sign certificate.
The main issues I was facing was related to LOCALHOST and GOOGLE CHROME (at least release 108) , because my test backend is in same dev machine.
I came up with a solution to generate self signed certificate that is OK for Google Chrome with domain like 'localhost'.
When generating the server certificate, you need to add an extension file that is adding some DNS and the IP address (IP4 & IP6) of 'localhost'.
Also important to import your root CA in Chrome to avoid Reject unauthorized...

**steps to create CA and certificates**

```
1- generate your root CA. It has to be imported in Google Chrome
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -days 999 -keyout ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=City/O=whatevev/OU=whatevev/CN=your name if you want/emailAddress=test@test.com"

2- generate the server private key and CSR
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout server-key.pem -out server-req.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=City/O=whatevev/OU=whatevev/CN=your name if you want/emailAddress=test@test.com"

3- finaly generate the server key, with some additional conf (see below)
openssl x509 -req  -days 999 -in server-req.pem -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out server-cert.pem -extfile server-ext.conf
```

**example of server-ext.conf file that prevent chrome from complaining about wrong DNS or anything else**

can fine more information about this extension file [HERE](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/x509v3_config.html)

```
subjectAltName=DNS:test.home,DNS:localhost.home,DNS:localhost,IP:0.0.0.0,IP:127.0.0.1,IP:::1
```

Finally, on your BACKEND, you can configure your nodejs express server using your root CA and the certificate/key :

```
const httpsOptions: https.ServerOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(
      path.join(__dirname, "auth", "certificats", "server-key.pem")
    ),

    cert: fs.readFileSync(
      path.join(__dirname, "auth", "certificats", "server-cert.pem")
    ),

    ca: fs.readFileSync(
      path.join(__dirname, "auth", "certificats", "ca-cert.pem")
    ),

    passphrase: "passpahrase of root CA,
  };
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, sure, the CN= should indicate the server name. Often it is easier to change the hosts file to point to 127.0.0.1 for a given server name if you want to self-host on the same machine. Verifying a certificate without verifying the server name makes no sense: you'd trust **anybody** that has received a certificate from a CA if that was the case, regardless of the website name.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes  'CN= should indicate the server name'. maybe but the issue about bad certifiacte is not related to CN. If you check my example, CN is set with "your name if you want".
The most important part to fix the Pb is the extension file to add when signing the certificate and add the localhost DNS and IPs (both V4 & V6). These are the key information. Il you remove the IPs and DNS, Google Chome complains about certificate. Hope this helps

Comment: Oh, yeah, nowadays the extensions are used for server names. Sorry, got that from the past :) Anyway, same thing, better to add your servername than to use localhost as destination - that's not so flexible.

Comment: cool. Please accept my answer so that others could find it in case of similar issue

Comment: Nobody but you can accept answers on your own question. However, it takes 48 hours after you've answered so that others can post answers as well. I can just vote up :) - what I forget to do sometimes honestly, not out of spite or even ignorance, but because I'm solution oriented.

Comment: got it thks ;-)